# How to add a column to a dataframe and assign conditional values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple dataframe, where I want to add a new column(col3) with values determined by the values from 'col1'. If the value from 'col1' starts with A, I want to put 'A' to col3. And a similar thing to the value that starts with B.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {"col1" : ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"], "col2" : [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df['col1'].str[:1]`? It seems like your actual problem can't be this simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {"col1" : ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"], "col2" : [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['col3']=np.where((df.col1.str.startswith('A')),'A',df.col1)
df['col3']=np.where((df.col1.str.startswith('B')),'B',df.col3)
df
```

#### Output

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   A1  1     A
1   A2  2     A
2   B1  3     B
3   B2  4     B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {"col1" : ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"], "col2" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['col3']=df["col1"].str[0]
print(df)
```

This results you in

```
    col1  col2  col3
0   A1     1    A
1   A2     2    A
2   B1     3    B
3   B2     4    B
4   C1     5    C
5   C2     6    C
```

Comment: this logic is weird. Is `df.col1.str.startswith(df.col1.str[0]))` always `True`? Is there any scenario causing it `False`? If it is always `True`, why don't you just use straight `df['col3'] = df.col1.str[0]`